# Mysql left join, group by, count and union all

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Heres my query

```
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
```

`fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing` table

```
  master_listing_id   dispatch_code_id
          2                 2
          5                 2
          36                2
          37                2
          134               2
          135               2
          136               2
          137               2
          138               2
          139               2
          140               2
```

`fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered` table

```
  master_listing_id   dispatch_code_id
          1                 2
```

`fsi_master_listing` table

```
  master_listing_id   transmittal_id
          1                 1
          2                 1
          5                 2
          36                2
          37                2
          134               3
          135               3
          136               3
          137               3
          138               3
          139               3
          140               3
```

`fsi_transmittals` table

```
  transmittal_id   product_name
        1             Name 1
        2             Name 2
        3             Name 3
```

What Im trying to do is to get the combined result of product from `fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing` and `fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered` where dispatch_code_id='2' and count them

My desire Output would be

```
  Product Name    Product Count
     Name 1            2
     Name 2            3
     Name 3            7
```

Thanks in advance, hope somebody can help me to this..

Comment: **This cannot be true** `SELECT fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id` Your select has 4 cols you get 2 cols in result?

Comment: I didn't put the other cols

Comment: I think that @lad2025 was on to something when he suggested using `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`.  But could you update your outputs to show _all_ the columns?  This is the source of confusion I believe.

Comment: The other col is not really important to me.. I just need the transmittal_id to be grouped.

Comment: We need to see the other columns because this may be why adding `UNION` did not fix it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I edited my question.

Comment: Your desired output does not let us determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are selecting columns in your query which are not aggregates or fields specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.  I suggest you update your question and let us know what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: I'm glad I don't have to work with this naming policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS Product_Count
FROM
(SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=2
 ) AS sub
 GROUP BY product_name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377737)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ product_name ║ Product_Count ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Name 1       ║             2 ║
║ Name 2       ║             3 ║
║ Name 3       ║             7 ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
 GROUP BY fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
 GROUP BY fsi_transmittals.product_name
```

OR

```
SELECT fsi_transmittals.product_name, SUM(fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id) AS transmittal_id 
FROM ( SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
 GROUP BY fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)." )
GROUP BY fsi_transmittals.product_name
```

Comment: Would you mind also telling us what this query does differently?

Comment: first query doesn't work, I still get same result. 2nd is error

Comment: can you give table with data? @joel. you can try now.